# How to remove duplicate comma separated character values from each cell of a column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data-manipulation

I have a data-frame with 2 columns ID and Product as below :

```
ID  Product
A   Clothing, Clothing Food, Furniture, Furniture
B   Food,Food,Food, Clothing
C   Food, Clothing, Clothing
```

I need to have only unique products for each ID, for example :

```
ID  Product
A   Clothing, Food, Furniture
B   Food, Clothing
C   Food, Clothing
```

How do I do this using R

Comment: You fix the problem using `unique` before you do your aggregation.

Comment: Do you have `Clothing` and `Clothing Food` as separate entries?

Comment: No, that was a mistake, it should be Clothing, Food

Answer (score 4):

If there are multiple delimiters in the dataset, one way would be to split the 'Product' column using all the delimiters, get the `unique` and then `paste` it together (`toString`) grouped by 'ID'.  Here we use `data.table` methods.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Product= toString(unique(strsplit(Product, 
            ',\\s*|\\s+')[[1]]))), by = ID]
#   ID                   Product
#1:  A Clothing, Food, Furniture
#2:  B            Food, Clothing
#3:  C            Food, Clothing
```